# Android - production release Your app includes non compliant SDK version com.kochava.base:tracker

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

I uploaded my Android app on google play console, While submitting app it is showing error.

Google Play Console:

[image]

After I am upgrading kochava version to 3.11.0, still it is displaying error.
Could someone please help on the same.